# How to revert an approved edit for answer

Tags: feature-request, support, edits, suggested-edits

Consider this suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4555066

Here the editor has made a factual error, albeit minor, but it adds nothing to original answer (which was useful to at least 14 people, judging from the number of upvotes).

Of course the easiest thing for me is to edit the post back to reflect its previous state, but it would have been more convenient to have an option to revert the question back to the previous version.

Comment: What is the factual error in the edit?  I see none.

Comment: its not `objToExtend`, its `objToGetPropsFrom`

Comment: it had a neutral name - x, but after rename the name started to mean the opposite from what its being used for.

Comment: @Duncan He means that the variable that the editor renamed was renamed to something that the variable doesn't logically represent.  The method isn't extending that object, it's getting values from it, so calling it the object to extend when you're not extending it is confusing and misleading.

Comment: Unfortunately, many reviewers pay scant attention. I pay extra attention to any suggested edit on a post with upvotes, normally with a bias toward rejecting on the basis that the upvoters found the post useful. On some occasions, the editor may have added more-recent information, or corrected a link. Making a decision takes time, and often by the time I've come to a conclusion, the edit is approved where I'd've rejected it. Perhaps the minimum-rep-to-review should increase as the upvote-count grows? And I'm not sure whether this should be a comment or an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "rollback" option that you can use on the revision history of any question to roll back an edit that you feel was actively harmful.

Note that edits that are too minor, but not *actively harmful* generally shouldn't be rolled back.  While they should be rejected at first, rolling back an excessively minor edit is just as bad as making an excessively minor edit.

Comment: yes, there is such button on **questions**, but i'm asking about **answers**

Comment: @c69 It exists for all posts.  It is not specific to questions.

Comment: ahh, you need to **middle click** (open in new window) the edit link